# How to update Ttk.Progressbar in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a siplme GUI that performs a few time-consuming operations. I would like to make a progressbar that would update after each of this operations. However it seems impossible to be done.

No solutions with update or update_idletask worked (or I used it in a wrong manner). So the aim is that progressbar is updated in every loop iteration. And solution with .after() rather will not be suitable here, as the function is run bybutton click.

Sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from time import sleep

def RunThat():
   global pb
   for i in range(0,101,10):
      pb["value"]=i
      pb.update()  #this works
      sleep(0.1)
      print(i)

master=Tk()

Label(master,text="Doing something...").grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10)
Grid.columnconfigure(master,0,weight=1)
Label(master,text="Progress:",justify=LEFT).grid(row=1,column=0,padx=25,pady=2,sticky=W+S)
Grid.rowconfigure(master,1,weight=1)
pb=Progressbar(master)
pb.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=25,pady=2,sticky=W+E)   
pb["maximum"]=100
pb["value"]=0  
Button(master,text="Do it",command=RunThat).grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without question, the only way for the progressbar to update is for the event loop to run so that it can service the event that requests a redraw. When you ask the application to sleep, or have a long running function, the event loop is not able to service requests.

This means you must call `update` or `update_idletasks`, refactor your long running function to work with the event loop, or you need to run this function in a separate process or thread.

Comment: but as I wrote, in my app update or update_idletasks do not work. But strangely for sample code they work. So what am I missing?

Comment: @misery: your example doesn't call either of those. Are we supposed to guess how you tried to use them?

Comment: The only difference between sample code an my app code is that pb in my app is a child of a frame, that is a child of the master. Can this be a reason?

Comment: Damn, what a stupid mistake, another progress bar had the same name. Sorry. Im voting to close this question. update works.

Comment: Running 2.7.11 on MacOS Sierra. update_idletasks didn't work on it's own but using it together with update did the trick.